dateFormatter with Xcode 15 no is not working and return nil
I had no problem with Xcode 14, but when migrating to Xcode 15.3 dateFormatter now return false in my code. I use dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss" and dateFormatter.date(from: 2014-04-19) returns false
my code:
func dateFormat(from dateString: String) -> String? {
  let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
  dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
        
  if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString) { // With 2024-04-19 returns nil
    //...
  }

  return nil
}

in this case dateFormat rerun nil
This fix the problem but dont works for me when I don't know the time zone of the date:
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)

